# Make exception when replacing diacritics with regular characters

Tags: javascript, unicode, diacritics

Trying to make an exception to all characters that have been converted to regular letters.

`txtValue.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');`

As you can see, I replace all the special characters for normal letters, but now I would like to add an exception for the char "ç" and it's capital equivalent "Ç", which are `u00e7` and `u00c7` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only simple way I see is not optimized but do the job properly :

```js
const text = "Çééé éÇé àç" // test this string
  .replace(/\u00e7/g, '__minC__') // save wanted chars position
  .replace(/\u00c7/g, '__majC__')
  .normalize('NFD') // normalize to prepare diacritic edit
  .replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, '') // replace all diacritics
  .replace(/__minC__/g, 'ç') // restore wanted chars
  .replace(/__majC__/g, 'Ç')
  
  console.log(text)
```

In this case we use `\p{Diacritic}` from [Unicode Property Escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes)